# frama-c slicing plugin appears to discard used stack values

Tags: c, frama-c, program-slicing, acsl

### Problem description

I'm developing a frama-c plugin that uses the slicing plugin as a library to remove unused bits of automatically generated code. Unfortunately the slicing plugin drops a bunch of stack values, which are actually used. They are used in so far as their addresses are contained in structures that are handed of to abstract external functions.

### Simple example

This is a simpler example that models the same general structure I have.

```c
/* Abstract external function */
void some_function(int* ints[]);

int main() {
  int i;
  int *p = &i;
  int *a[] = { &p };
  some_function(a);
  return 0;
}
```

When slicing this example with `frama-c-gui -slice-calls some_function experiment_slicing.c` (I haven't figures out how to see the slicing output when invoking the command line without gui) it drops everything but the declaration `int *a[];` and the call to `some_function`.

### Attempted fixes

I tried fixing it by adding ACSL annotations.
However what I believed to be the sensible specification (see below) did not work

```c
/*@ requires \valid(ints) && \valid(ints[0]);
 */
void some_function(int* ints[]);
```

I then tried with an assign (see below) which does have the desired behaviour. however it is not a correct specification, since the function never actually writes to the pointer but needs to read it for correct functionality. I am worried that if I move ahead with such an incorrect specification it will lead to weird problems down the line.

```c
/*@ requires \valid(ints) && \valid(ints[0]);
   assigns  *ints;
*/
void some_function(int* ints[]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track: it is the `assigns` clause that you should use here: it will indicate which parts of the memory state are concerned by a call to an undefined function. However, you need to provide a complete `assigns` clause, with its `\from` part (that indicates which memory location are read to compute the new value of the memory location written to).

I have added an `int` variable to your example, as your function isn't returning a result (`void` return type). For a function that is returning something, you should also have a clause `assigns \result \from ...;`:

```c
int x;

/*@ assigns x \from indirect:ints[..], *(ints[..]); */
void some_function(int* ints[]);

int main() {
  int i;
  int*p = &i;
  int *a[] = { &p };
  some_function(a);
  return 0;
}
```

The `assigns` clause indicates that `some_function` might change the value of `x`, and that the new value will be computed from the addresses stored in `ints[..]`
(the `indirect` label tells that we're not using their value directly, this is described in more detail in section 8.2 of [Eva's manual](https://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-eva-manual.pdf)), and their content.

using `frama-c -slice-calls some_function file.c -then-last -print` (the last arguments are here to print the resulting file on the standard output: `-then-last` indicates that the following options should operate on the last Frama-C project created, in that case the one resulting from the slicing, and `-print` prints the C code of said project. You may also use `-ocode output.c` to redirect the pretty-printing of the code into `output.c`.) gives the following result:

```c
* Generated by Frama-C */
void some_function(int **ints);

void main(void)
{
  int i;
  int *p = & i;
  int *a[1] = {(int *)(& p)};
  some_function(a);
  return;
}
```

Note in addition that your example is not well-typed: `&p` is a pointer to pointer to int, and should thus be stored in an `int**` array, not an `int*` array. But I assume that it only stems from reducing your original example and is does not matter much for slicing itself.

Comment: Thank you that was a really good description. I tried it with the `assigns \result \from`, works like a charm.
A refinement question: Say `some_function` neither modifies state, nor returns anything, but I need to preserve it for a side effect (failing assert). Is there a clean way to model this with `assigns`?

PS: Yes the typing was accidental, it should have just been `{p}`

Comment: No, I'm afraid it is not possible to model cleanly a function that might not terminate (from the caller point of view, an assert failure in the callee is a non-termination case in the sense that the remainder of the code never gets executed) with just `assigns`.

Comment: Plus this kind of "effect" is very hard to keep through slicing, at least the one from Frama-C.